# How to calculate thread sleeping time between context switch

Tags: multithreading, scheduler

I have application with 1000 threads.

How to calculate how long each thread can sleep until operation system scheduler switch context to it?

Comment: Assuming the threads are cpu bound, not waiting for resources, a single non-hyper threading core, then time slicing occurs at the "tick" rate. For Windows the default is 64hz == 15.625 ms per tick, so 15.625 seconds for each thread (of the 1000 threads) to get a time slice. The rate can be increased using [timeBeginPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx) to 1000hz = 1ms per tick, in which case it's 1 second for each thread to get a time slice. With 4 hyper threading cores, 8 threads would run at the same time.

Comment: @rcgldr I think, you can make your comment as answer, this is very helpfull for me!